# Inspector shows margin-top for html, but how do I access that via css?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, margin

I have a strange issue. I copied the bootstrap album but in my project I get a margin-top of 32px that I can't remove.

[image]

I used the inspector to see its sitting in html and has a property of 32px for the margin. I can remove this in the inspector and it will go. But where do I actually add "margin-top: 0px !important;" in my code.
There is no explicit code in my front-page.php nor header.php

front-page.php

```
<?php
    get_header()
?>

<header>
  <div class="nav-title collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
          <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
          <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
          <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-laptop" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V11H2V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11zm-11-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 3.5V12h14V3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 2h-11zM0 12.5h16a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 12.5z"/></svg>
        <strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Abdul Samad</strong>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>

  <section class="text-center container banner-color">
    <div class="row py-lg-5 banner-image" style="background-image: url('http://main-portfolio.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/banner_image.png')">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="banner-title banner-heading">Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
        <!-- CARD 1 -->
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>  
                <p class="card-text">Take a look at all my marketing achievements throughout my career. </p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <a href="https://abdul-samad.online/marketingportfolio/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary">View</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://bitbucket.org/asamad9134/my-marketing-portfolio/src/develop/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-warning">Bitbucket Repo</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CARD 2 -->
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>  
                <p class="card-text">Take a look at all my marketing achievements throughout my career. </p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <a href="https://abdul-samad.online/marketingportfolio/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary">View</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://bitbucket.org/asamad9134/my-marketing-portfolio/src/develop/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-warning">Bitbucket Repo</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- CARD 3 -->
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>  
                <p class="card-text">Take a look at all my marketing achievements throughout my career. </p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <a href="https://abdul-samad.online/marketingportfolio/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary">View</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://bitbucket.org/asamad9134/my-marketing-portfolio/src/develop/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-medium btn-warning">Bitbucket Repo</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>

<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
    <p class="mb-0">New to Bootstrap? <a href="/">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../getting-started/introduction/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
  </div>
</footer>


    <script src="../abduls-theme/assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.88.1">

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/album/">

    <?php wp_head() ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class() 
?>
```

Comment: The code you provided has no `margin` issues in my end. Push an online version and send us a link. That should be the actual post and not just copy/pasting your entire raw code.

Comment: See in inspector which class is having the margin property and then override that class in your code with `margin: 0 !important`.

Comment: WordPress (which you should have tagged the question with btw.) adds this, when an admin user is logged in, and the top admin navigation bar is shown. Can't say it doesn't show here in this instance though.

Comment: @CBroe lol you genius. I doubted this because why would it be all white? But when I tried it in incognito mode it was gone. Thank you :)

Comment: Normally it shouldn't be white, but show the admin menu in that place. It gets fixed positioned, so the margin-top gets added to `html` to push all the rest of the page content down, so that the menu doesn't make any content at the very top of the page inaccessible.